# Is the performance benefit of a logback AsyncAppender diluted when in a k8s container that simply writes to stdout?

Tags: java, kubernetes, logback

Before we deployed services to Kubernetes, we used to write logs to files.  There have been times that some of that information we were logging was considerable.  In those situations, it is definitely worth considering using a logback AsyncAppender, to get a little bit better performance.

If these services are running in a Kubernetes container, where we write logs directly to stdout, and other processes are collecting stdout and sending it to a log aggregator, I would think the performance questions are different.

Is there evidence that in this kind of situation, implementing an AsyncAppender, as opposed to just a synchronous appender, would make an appreciable difference in performance?  Setting up testbeds to get reliable measurements of this will be a significant undertaking.  I've seen documentation of results testing async appenders while writing to files, but I think that isn't quite the same situation.

Can anyone document real performance differences with AsyncAppenders in this kind of environment?

Answer (score 1):

Stdout/err from the container is, usually, connected to a file. It's possibly via some number of pipes rather than a direct thing but somewhere under all of it is probably still a disk that needs to keep up with all the writes. That said, the pipe buffers in your CRI plugin can probably eat most spikes and level them out so "diluted" might be fair, but that depends on the specifics of your CRI and how it's configured.